# How to import code from git submodule in aws lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an application `app.py` which uses a module called `modelling` from `modelling.py` which is present in git submodule.
The directory structure:

```
app.py
|
|-modelling (git submodule)
    |-modelling.py
```

I need to import a function from modelling.py which is inside a git submodule. This app.py is deployed to AWS lambda.

**AWS LAMBDA RUNS MY app.py. Basically the app.py script is written in the lambda**

When I run this lambda function.

I get the error

```
'errorMessage': "Unable to import module 'modelling': No module named 'modelling'
```

at

```
from modelling.modelling. import mod_func
```

in the lambda function.

Basically it is not able to make the git sub-module folder to import from the script.

*How to make the git sub-module as a folder in AWS Lambda, which will allow me to import from the lambda itself?.*

Comment: It sounds like you aren't including that folder in the .zip file you deploy to Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you initialized the submodule correctly? Sounds like you did not run the following command:

```
git submodule update --init
```